# Mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

MVT in words : 
If it took 10 hours to travel 1000 km, then you must have seen 1000/10 = 100 kmph in your speedometer at least once.

Am I correct in saying this :  Assuming your initial and final speeds are 0, you would be seeing ALL the speeds between 0 kmph and 100kmph (Before seeing 100kmph, you would see 98kmph, 99kmph, etc...)

See something wrong in above reasoning ?

Comment: Who on earth uses "kmph"? It's "km/h" for the civilized people and "mph" for the Americans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the "intermediate value theorem".  While the derivative of a function is NOT necessarily continuous, derivatives satisfy the "intermediate value theorem".  If f'(a)= 0 and, at some b, f'(b)= f'(b)= 100  then f'(x) takes on every value between 0 and 100 someplace between a and b.

Comment: Here is some additional info on that: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))

Comment: Thank you :) I wish my textbook mentioned about this under MVT as it seems pretty general...  Not sure but it seems all differentiable functions have continuous derivatives.

Comment: This isn't the same as what is usually called the intermediate value theorem. The IVT says _continuous functions_ have the intermediate value property; this theorem --- Darboux's theorem --- says derivatives have the intermediate value property even when the derivatives are not continuous.